# using regex or replace to extract only string and remove string after numeric value

Tags: c#

How to remove text after any numeric value
Eg - asb123bh
output should be - asb

Tried indexof and replace methods but this dint work out

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you attempt to get the text(s) before the numeric characters.

```
([^\d]+)(?=\d+).*
```

`([^\d]+)` - Capturing group for non-numeric character.

`(?=\d+)` - Positive lookahead, match the first group followed by numbers.

`.*` - Match any character if any.

[Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/LYtNUf/1)

---

If the pattern is matched, get the value from the first group: `match.Groups[1]`.

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^\d]+)(?=\d+).*");
string input = "asb123bh";
        
Match match = regex.Match(input);
Console.WriteLine(match.Success);
        
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

Or using the `regex.Replace(/* input */, /* pattern to replace */)` to replace the current string to new string with first capturing group.

```cs
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, "$1"));
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooFajZ)

Comment: it is not working for text "asb 123 bh"

Comment: Please provide list of sample input & expected result. Thanks.

Comment: @Sailajakowkuntla - I would assume this is the input, isn't it? so the expected output is `INGOSSTRAKH Tel: +7` because after the 7 there is a whitespace (a non-numeric value) and everything should be removed at that point

Comment: @RandRandom, this opposed to the original question in which the Post owner wanted the text before the numeric value. Would be great if he can attach the input & desired output in the question.